# How does .addOn work / execute in this leaflet example code?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am still inexperienced with javascript and trying understand this code -

when / how does info.onAdd execute when it's not exclusively called w/o parameter?

According to leaflet documentation, this is a native method, but a function is assigned to the name?

```
var info = L.control();

info.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'); // create a div with a class "info"
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};

// method that we will use to update the control based on feature properties passed
info.update = function (props) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>US Population Density</h4>' +  (props ?
        '<b>' + props.name + '</b><br />' + props.density + ' people / mi<sup>2</sup>'
        : 'Hover over a state');
};

info.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

In programming, a "[method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming))" is indeed a function, but attached to an object (or instance of a class).

In the code example you provide, this method is overridden by another function. This is also a standard practice, to customize the object behaviour.

Your code does not look to call the `onAdd` method, because it is called by Leaflet:

1. `addTo` performs some operations, mainly calling the `map`'s `addControl` method.
2. `addControl` registers the `info` Control, and calls `infos`'s `onAdd` method.
3. `onAdd` executes and returns an HTMLElement that the `map` can use to display the `info` on the viewport.